# A lot of empty <option> list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Wordpress Woocommerce and I want to display the list of products by certain category. Here is the code:

```
<form method="POST" action="booktable.php">
<?php 
$args = array(
'product_cat' => 'test-restaurant',
'post_type' => 'product',
'orderby' => 'title',
);
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
echo "<select name='booktable'>";
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
$products->the_post();
?>      
<option value="<?php the_ID(); ?> "> <?php the_title(); ?>    
<?php
}
echo "</select>";
?>
<input type="submit" value="Book">
</form>
```

I'm getting the result I want but the problem is that in dropdown list there are a lot of empty options as well, like miltiple this:

```
<option value=" "></option>
```

Could you help me to figure out what is causing problem?

Answer (score 1):

`product_cat` argument is not a valid one. Look at the [wp_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) possible arguments and values need.

The possible values are

> ```
> cat (int) - use category id.
> category_name (string) - use category slug.
> category__and (array) - use category id.
> category__in (array) - use category id.
> category__not_in (array) - use category id.
> ```

Don't forget, if you loop through woocommerce products you can make different to retrieve some product datas, use tax_query or meta_query to reach details from product.

In fact the taxonomy use for the product can not be find with the usual category query. You need to use tax_query and choose the proper tax you are looking for, `product_cat` or `product_tag`

```
$args = array(             
         'post_type' => 'product',
         'orderby' => 'title',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page' => 15, 
         'tax_query'=> array(
              array(
                'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug', 
                'terms'         => 'test-restaurant',
                'operator'      => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
              )
         ),
         'meta_query' => array(
              array(
                 'key'           => '_visibility',
                 'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
                 'compare'       => 'IN'
             )
         ),
);
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
echo "<select name='booktable'>";
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
     // if you need to retrieve the sku 
     $product_data = new WC_Product($product->ID);       
     $sku = $product_data->get_sku();
?>      
 <option value="<?php echo $product->ID; ?> "> <?php echo $product->post_title; ?>  </option>  
<?php
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not helping. When I use category_name instead of product_cat nothing is displayed at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot but there is same problem: a lot of empty dropdown options.

Comment: Do you have variable product ? you maybe need to add a meta_query for the visible product, 'meta_query'            => array(
        array(
            'key'           => '_visibility',
            'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
            'compare'       => 'IN'
        )
    ),